# Swapping the order of a limit and a non-linear functional acting on a sequence of compact operators of increasing rank.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics

Let $\rho_{n}$ be some compact operator for all $n$ ( I know finite-dimensional operators are compact, forgive the redundancy) and let the rank of $\rho_{n}$ equal to $n$.

Now, let $F$ be some non-linear functional mapping from compact operators to the reals, think trace, quantum fidelity, trace norm etc. What are necessary and sufficient conditions for the following to hold?

$$\lim_{n}F(\rho_{n}) = F(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\rho_{n})$$

I know that for infinite dimensional compact operators there are some issues owing to the fact that certain functionals are no longer continuous when acting on spaces of infinite dimensional operators.

Comment: In which sense does the limit $\lim \rho_n$ exist?

Comment: $\| \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \rho_{n}\|_{1} <\infty$. The limit exists in a strong sense with respect to the trace norm defined as $\|A\|_{1} := \frac{1}{2}Tr|A|$. I hope that answers your question.